# How do I query a pair of objects from a single Django Model efficiently?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a Track model and currently I do a nested loop through the models id to get the pair and then pass it into a function to count the similarity between these two non-equivalent track object

```
track_set = Track.objects.all()

track_ids = [track.id for track in track_set]
pointer_a = 0
pointer_b = 1

for pointer_a in range(len(track_ids) - 1):
    for pointer_b in range(pointer_a + 1, len(track_ids)):
        track_a = Track.objects.get(pk=track_ids[pointer_a])
        track_b = Track.objects.get(pk=track_ids[pointer_b])
        counter += 1
        count_it_sim(track_a, track_b)
```

I think the way I get the object is not very efficient, is there any way to optimize it ?

**Edit:** this `count_it_sim` will calculate the similarity value between track_a and track_b, and I need to calculate it for all the pairs in Track model
`models.py`

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Tagged(models.Model):
    track = models.ForeignKey(Track, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    frequency = models.IntegerField(
        default=0,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
    )
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('track', 'tag')

class Track(models.Model):
    track_id = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, through='Tagged', blank=True)
    similarity = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        blank=True,
        through='Similar',
        related_name='similar_to',
        symmetrical=False
    )
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='PlayTrack', blank=True)

class Similar(models.Model):
    track1 = models.ForeignKey(Track, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='track1')
    track2 = models.ForeignKey(Track, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='track2')
    similarity = models.FloatField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(1)],
    )
```

and what count_it_sim will do is, it will get all tag's frequency of track_a and track_b through a associative entity, which is Tagged model, and calculate it to get the similarity value between track_a and track_b

```
def count_it_sim(track_a: Track, track_b: Track):
    tag_set = Tag.objects.all()
    part1 = 0
    part2 = 0
    part3 = 0
    for tag in tag_set:
        try:
            freq_tag_of_track_a = Tagged.objects.get(track=track_a, tag=tag).frequency
        except Tagged.DoesNotExist:
            continue
        try:
            freq_tag_of_track_b = Tagged.objects.get(track=track_b, tag=tag).frequency
        except Tagged.DoesNotExist:
            continue
        part1 += freq_tag_of_track_a * freq_tag_of_track_b
        part2 += freq_tag_of_track_a ** 2
        part3 += freq_tag_of_track_b ** 2
    try:
        it_sim = part1 / (math.sqrt(part2) * math.sqrt(part3))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        it_sim = None
```

**Edit 2:** On count_it_sim, instead of iterate through all of the tags from `Tag.objects.all()`, I query only those tags which exist in `Tagged` and the result is way faster than the previous one, here is my current code now

```
def count_it_sim(track_a: Track, track_b: Track):
    filtered_tagged = Tagged.objects.filter(Q(track=track_a) | Q(track=track_b))
    tag_ids = filtered_tagged.values_list('tag', flat=True).distinct()
    part1 = 0
    part2 = 0
    part3 = 0
    for tag_id in tag_ids:
        try:
            freq_tag_of_track_a = filtered_tagged.get(track=track_a, tag__id=tag_id).frequency
        except Tagged.DoesNotExist:
            freq_tag_of_track_a = 0
        try:
            freq_tag_of_track_b = filtered_tagged.get(track=track_b, tag__id=tag_id).frequency
        except Tagged.DoesNotExist:
            freq_tag_of_track_b = 0
        part1 += freq_tag_of_track_a * freq_tag_of_track_b
        part2 += freq_tag_of_track_a ** 2
        part3 += freq_tag_of_track_b ** 2
    try:
        it_sim = part1 / (math.sqrt(part2) * math.sqrt(part3))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        it_sim = None
```

**Edit 3:** There are some changes in the models. Instead of storing the `frequency` of each `tag` of a `track`, now the `frequency` will be calculated by counting how many `users` have tag a `track` with a particular `tag`. Here is the update

```
# models.py
...
class Tagged(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    track = models.ForeignKey(Track, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
...
```

and the count_it_sim function become

```
def count_it_sim(track_a: Track, track_b: Track):
    filtered_tagged = Tagged.objects.filter(Q(track=track_a) | Q(track=track_b))
    tag_ids = filtered_tagged.values_list('tag', flat=True).distinct()
    part1 = 0
    part2 = 0
    part3 = 0
    for tag_id in tag_ids:
        try:
            freq_tag_of_track_a = filtered_tagged.filter(track=track_a, tag__id=tag_id).count()  # UPDATED LINE
        except Tagged.DoesNotExist:
            freq_tag_of_track_a = 0

        try:
            freq_tag_of_track_b = filtered_tagged.filter(track=track_b, tag__id=tag_id).count()  #UPDATED LINE
        except Tagged.DoesNotExist:
            freq_tag_of_track_b = 0
        part1 = accumulate(part1, freq_tag_of_track_a * freq_tag_of_track_b)
        part2 = accumulate(part2, freq_tag_of_track_a ** 2)
        part3 = accumulate(part3, freq_tag_of_track_b ** 2)
    try:
        it_sim = final_calc(part1, part2, part3)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        it_sim = None
    return it_sim
```

Comment: What is "the similarity"? And what does `count_it_sim` do? Can you post your `models.py`?

Comment: @raratiru I've updated the question, thanks for asking

Comment: I understand that each `Track` can have many `Tagged` frequencies. For example here are 3 `Tracks`: `{track_id1: (tagged_freq1, tagged_freq2, tagged_freq3), track_id2: (tagged_freq2, tagged_freq4, tagged_freq5, tagged_freq7), track_id3: (tagged_freq5, tagged_freq6, tagged_freq3, tagged_freq2, tagged_freq1)}`. And you want to gather those data to manipulate them, with one database hit. Correct?

Comment: yes, but doesn't have to with one database hit if it isn't possible

Comment: @raratiru also, I've managed to improve the performance and I've added the code snippets on the question

Comment: Did you [solve it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: @raratiru not yet, I was refactoring some models and also there are some changes in the Tagged model, so the way I get the frequency is different now. I've updated the question.

Comment: The idea of gathering the data into **memory**, with the least database hits at the very beginning, was a radical groundbreaking change. It is the first building-block of your programing design. S.O. will help you finalize the work needed for each building block separately but not all of them at once because it unavoidably becomes very complicated.

Answer (score 3):

> I think the way I get the object is not very efficient, is there any way to optimize it ?

Well, you already have the objects (in `track_set`) so you don't need to fetch them again; you just need to get pairs of objects.

> What I need is (1,2) (1,3) (1,4) (2,3) (2,4) (3,4)

For that, you can use `itertools.combinations`:

```
import itertools

for a,b in itertools.combinations(track_set, 2):
   count_it_sim(a, b)
```

You will have to make sure you fetch the objects from the database in the right order; because there is no guarantee on how the items will be returned:

> If a query doesn’t have an ordering specified, results are returned
>   from the database in an unspecified order. A particular ordering is
>   guaranteed only when ordering by a set of fields that uniquely
>   identify each object in the results.

In your case, it seems you need them in primary key order; so I would modify the initial query to:

```
track_set = Track.objects.order_by('pk')
```

The [queryset documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) has details on `order_by` and the [model reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#ordering) has details on specifying the default ordering.

Comment: this line `for a,b in zip(*[iter(track_set)]*2):` isn't what I expected, assume that track_set is consist of [1,2,3,4], your code will result in (1,2) and (3,4). What I need is (1,2) (1,3) (1,4) (2,3) (2,4) (3,4)

Answer (score 1):

As per our discussion in the comments, the aim is to get the the needed data using the least number of database queries, in a structure that will easily allow further data manipulation.

We will try to fetch all the `Tagged.frequency` data that correspond to each `Track` in the following dictionary structure:

```
{
    track_id1: list(all_related_frequencies), 
    track_id2: list(all_related_frequencies),
}
```

The idea is to get all the `Track` instances and [prefetch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) their related `Tagged` instances in an attribute called `prefetched_tagged`.

Each instance of `Track` has an attribute `tagged_set` which allows [reverse access](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) to all the `Tagged` instances related to it. This is the query that prefetches them:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

the_data = (
    Track.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            'tagged_set',
            to_attr='prefetched_tagged',
        )
    ).all()
)
```

Now, we saved in `the_data` variable, all instances of `Track` where each instance has an attribute `prefetched_tagged` that contains a `list` of all `Tagged` instances related to each `Track` instance.

With the following dictionary comprehension, we iterate `the_data` variable to create a dictionary with all `Track.track_id` as keys. Each key, will have a `list` as its value wich will contain all its related `Tagged.frequency`.

To create the list, we will use a list comprehension, inside the dictionary comprehension:

```
result = {
    each_track.track_id: [
        each_tagged.frequency for each_tagged in each_track.prefetched_tagged
    ] for each_track in the_data
}
```

Now, the variable `result` contains the data in the structure we need in order to further manipulate them. It took 2 database hits in order to load all the database data into memory. This is the whole code that also measures the database hits:

```
from django import db
from django.db.models import Prefetch

db.reset_queries()    

the_data = (
    Track.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            'tagged_set',
            to_attr='prefetched_tagged',
        )
    ).all()
)

result = {
    each_track.track_id: [
        each_tagged.frequency for each_tagged in each_track.prefetched_tagged
    ] for each_track in the_data
}

print(result)
print ("Queries Used: {0}".format(len(db.connection.queries))
```

Comment: I also need to know the tag_id of each frequency actually. As you can see on the `count_it_sim`, I need to calculate the frequency of the tag_j for track_a and track_b. With `result`, I can't properly match track_a and track_b with the same tag

Comment: @EdwinHarly I can think of two formats that can be used: either `{track_id1:((freq1, tag_id1), (freq2, tag_id2))}` or `{track_id1:((freq1, freq2), (tag_id1, tag_id2))}`. The `tag_id` does not cause any database hit because it is already saved in the `Tagged` model as `Tagged.tag_id`. The order is always the same because our source is the list called `prefetched_tagged`.